# NSURLConnection, tracking which connection is returning data

Tags: objective-c, ios, design-patterns, nsurlconnection, nsmutabledictionary

For the iOS app I'm working on, I'm currently writing a singleton class that handles asynchronous requests to a server. Here's an example of one of the methods -

```
- (void)registerUser:(CBCUserRegistration *)userRegistration delegate:(id)<CBCUserRegistrationDelegate>delegate;
```

within this method, an NSURLConnection is created and sends an asynchronous request. At this point, i need a way to tie the delegate object to the NSURLConnection, so thats when

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
```

is called, I know which delegate to inform. Because the requests are asynchronous, there may be more than one request going at any time. My initial though was to use an NSMutableDictionary, setting the NSURLConnection as the key and the delegate as the value, but the keys are copied so thats a no go. Can anyone suggest another way to track this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using an NSDictionary for this. Instead take an object-oriented approach:

Write a class `MyConnection` that implements the required `NSURLConnectionDelegate` callbacks and has a property/ivar of the `id<CBCUserRegistrationDelegate>`type. Add a `start` method to `MyConnection` that creates an `NSURLConnection`, assigns itself a delegate of that connection, and starts it. Now you can create an instance of `MyConnection` for every URL request you do. `MyConnection` keeps hold of the `CBCUserRegistrationDelegate` and forwards the result it receives from the `NSURLConnection`.

However, using delegate here is a bit old-fashioned. Use blocks instead, especially if your project uses ARC. `NSURLConnection` provides a convenient method to do async requests: `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]`.

For example:

```
- (void)registerUser:(CBCUserRegistration *)userRegistration delegate:(id<CBCUserRegistrationDelegate>)delegate
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.com/register"]];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        [delegate processRegistrationResponseData:data];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Great answer Leo! I think I'll go with blocks on this one, that'l simplify things a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Nice. Keep in mind that under ARC the delegate is retained by the block. So as long a the request is ongoing, the delegate will be retained.

Answer (score 0):

Use a NSNumber set to the address of the NSURLConnection as the key, and then you can set another dictionary as the object of the key. You can give it a name, etc, record the object to notify etc. Just remember to remove it when the NSURLConnection is released.